# Angular Luxon DateTime object Showing as String

Tags: angular, nswag, luxon

Using Angular 11 with LuxonFormat DateTime, we're connecting to an API to collect information.

We're trying to format one of the DateTime's from the API using .toLocaleString(); but it's strangely not working, and also ".toFormat()" can not be found.

On closer inspection of one of the DateTime formats collected from the API, show as a string. I think this is because the nswag generated service-proxies.ts file from the Swagger API does:

```
DateTime.fromISO(_data["start"].toString())
```

The swagger definition shows:

```
"start": "2021-09-27T10:25:02.988Z",
```

and digging deeper:

```
string($date-time)
```

In our C# API, they're definitely defined as DateTime

At this stage I'm not sure where the problem lies, Swagger, Nswag, Angular, Luxon. Why do some dates work and generate to proper DateTime objects, and others, appear as strings?